# URL Rewriting through htaccess using parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite my query parameters URLs into without query parameters. My URLs are like

```
http://www.example.com/pages.php?id=12&url=page-name&page=1
http://www.example.com/tour.php?id=12&url=tour-name&page=1
http://www.example.com/gallery.php?id=12&url=gallery-name&page=1
```

into

```
http://www.example.com/pages/page-name/1
http://www.example.com/tour/tour-name/1
http://www.example.com/gallery/gallery-name/1
```

How to do this?

I tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pages.php?id=$1&Url=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you explain why you want to do this.

Comment: Hi Mats, I don't want to allow users to change id in url and point them to 404 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(?:/([0-9]+))$ $1.php?url=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Problem that you have is the nicer looking URL is missing the "id" value, and without that, you can't rewrite it *with* an id value. Mod rewrite can't pull that out of thin air, so you either need to include it in the nicer looking URL or rely on the script to be able to pull the page based on the "url" parameter:

```
http://www.domain.com/tour/12/tour-name/1
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your help. But still it's not working it's serving 404 Page.